# How to read a chunk of 256 bytes in R?

Tags: r, byte, chunks

I am new to R language. I have a file named testing.exe and I want to read every 256-byte out of it in R.

I had came across the site https://www.r-bloggers.com/example-10-1-read-a-file-byte-by-byte/ to fit to my case:

```
finfo = file.info("testing.exe")
toread= file("testing", "rb")
alldata = readBin(toread, raw(256), n = finfo$size, endian="little")
```

but alldata gives me raw(0). What does it mean? I expect alldata will give a series of bytes values? How shall i modify the code? Thank you!

Comment: After implemented using MrFlick's method below, now I come into another problem: how can I store each chunk in a list or vector? so that later each chunk can be used to calculate its entropy value? I managed to use chunk <- as.character(chunk), then use table(chunk) for calculate entropy. But I need to store this in a list just like defaultdict(list) does in python. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really read a bunch of 256 byte chunks all in one call. You can either read the entire file...

```
fname <- "testing.exe"
finfo <- file.info(fname)
toread <- file(fname, "rb")
alldata <- readBin(toread, raw(), n = finfo$size, endian="little")
close(toread)
```

or you can loop to read chunks at a time

```
fname <- "testing.exe"
toread <- file(fname, "rb")
repeat {
  chunk <- readBin(toread, raw(), n = 256, endian="little")
  if (length(chunk)==0) break;
  print(chunk);
}
close(toread)
```

Comment: Thank you! I just figured it out after playing with the raw and n.